# Apollo Client HttpLink does not send cookies with "same-origin" in subdomain scenario

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, apollo-client

Apollo's HttpLink does not send cookies with the "same-origin" policy, although "same-origin" is satisfied in the present scenario according to the specification:

- **auth.example.com** sets cookies for the domain **example.com**
- the cookies should be sent on requests to **api.example.com**

The subdomains should fall under "same-origin", but the cookies are not sent along (API responds with 401 because of missing cookies, also confirmed in browsers network analysis).
CORS is configured correctly (incl. access-control-allow-credentials). The fact that api.exmaple.com is a CNAME DNS record and finally lands on a different domain should not matter, according to my research, because the client does not notice this at the time of the request.

This is my HttpLink:

```
const hasuraHttpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'api.example.com',
  credentials: 'same-origin'
});
```

Interestingly, this problem does not occur with Apollo's WebSocketLink, this works fine.

Can anyone confirm this or find find an error in my assumptions?